# Broadcast error in scipy but the arrays are the same shape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use the scipy statistical functions,

```
prior = scipy.stats.truncnorm.pdf(x, a, b,
                                  loc=loc, scale=scale)
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
<ipython-input-32-9c0390b95343> in prior(values1, values2)
     69     # line 6352 return _norm_pdf(x) / self._delta
     70     prior = scipy.stats.truncnorm.pdf(x, a, b,
---> 71                                       loc=loc, scale=scale)
     72 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py in pdf(self, x, *args, **kwds)
   1669             goodargs = argsreduce(cond, *((x,)+args+(scale,)))
   1670             scale, goodargs = goodargs[-1], goodargs[:-1]
-> 1671             place(output, cond, self._pdf(*goodargs) / scale)
   1672         if output.ndim == 0:
   1673             return output[()]

/opt/anaconda3/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py in _pdf(self, x, a, b)
   6350 
   6351     def _pdf(self, x, a, b):
-> 6352         return _norm_pdf(x) / self._delta
   6353 
   6354     def _logpdf(self, x, a, b):

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4084,) (4100,)
```

But the arrays are all the same shape. When I put print statements in right before the call to truncnorm.pdf,

```
print(x.shape, a.shape, b.shape, loc.shape, scale.shape)
prior = scipy.stats.truncnorm.pdf(x, a, b,
                                  loc=loc, scale=scale)
```

I get,

```
(4100,) (4100,) (4100,) (4100,) (4100,)
```

confirming that.

I followed the process of calculating the pdf of the truncated normal in the _continuous_distns.py file to try to recreate it for myself and see if something was happening to mask one of the arrays internally,

```
import scipy.special as sc

def norm_cdf(x):
    return sc.ndtr(x)

def norm_sf(x):
    return norm_cdf(-x)

nb = norm_cdf(b)
na = norm_cdf(a)
sb = norm_sf(b)
sa = norm_sf(a)

# line 6345 - 6347, defining self._delta
print(np.where(a > 0,
               -(sb - sa),
               nb - na).shape)

# line 162 return np.exp(-x**2/2.0) / _norm_pdf_C
# defining _norm_pdf(x)
norm_pdf_C = np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
print((np.exp(-x**2/2.0) / norm_pdf_C).shape)
```

I get

```
(4100,)
(4100,)
```

which are correct and the same shape. So I'm at a loss as to what the problem is. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Could you post the traceback as an indented code block.  It's hard to read the current, especially to identify the "->" lines.  But even so, tracing an error like this deep in library code back to your inputs can be hard.  It's hard to relate the `x,a,b` variables to your following code and shape test.  Obviously from the error, some input, or array derived from the inputs is smaller (3606,).  But we don't have enough information to make any guess about that.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've edited the question as you requested. Is that better?

Comment: That's not the full traceback, is it?

Comment: Sorry about that. It just points to the line my code that I said was the problem so I didn't think it would be helpful to put that part of the traceback in.

Comment: Please, post the full traceback and shapes of `x`, `a`, `b`, `loc` and `scale`.

Comment: @MaxPierini - I have edited my original post. Does this help clarify the issue?

Comment: The key may be this `goodargs = argsreduce(cond, *((x,)+args+(scale,)))`.  The name suggests applying some sort of `cond` to `x` to remove "bad" values.  But I haven't used this package, read its docs, or studied the code.  So that's all a guess.

Comment: Thanks for the shapes but without the full traceback of `truncnorm.pdf` error it's hard to identify it.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, it's my thought as well that there seems to be some sort of masking going on that I can't identify or understand why some values would be considered "bad." Hopefully someone with experience with this package might be able to chime in

Comment: @MaxPierini May I ask what you think is missing from the traceback?

Comment: The exception type and details

Comment: Wait... how many PDFs do you want to get from `truncnorm.pdf`? If you want one PDF only, a b loc scale need to be scalars, not arrays. If you want more than one PDF, a b loc scale need to be reshaped.